# How to detect illicit content in images?

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence

Can you help me in providing a prototype to detect illicit content in images, using python.

Comment: Could you please 1st define what's an illicit content for you ? Crude images, crude text ?

Comment: First we'll have to define what "illicit" means.  It'd still be difficult, even if you could.

Comment: What do you mean by illicit content?

Comment: illicit images in the sense "illegal images" just like pornography image content.and the qn z to detect such content from a given image.thanq 4 immediate response n hope same to provide me solution :).

Comment: First we'll have to define what "pornography" means.

Comment: I doubt that it's practically possible to do so. But maybe with some massive AI using a huge database of images categorized into "illicit" and "ok". Have fun making the database. :)

Comment: In what world is pornography illegal?

Comment: @Daniel: In many worlds. Large parts of US for example. Much of the middle east. Norway. etc, etc.

Comment: Sarath - the area of computer science you are looking for is Computer vision AND AI, OpenCV is a computer vision lib with python bindings. However your task is nearly impossible to do, even if you manage to define it.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Just to make your brain cramp up, at the federal level in the US (different from the states) child porno is illegal, but it has to meet a bunch of criteria.  Further, the image has to be a known minor at the time the picture was taken.  No easy task to do other than manually.

Comment: This requires support from your local or national law enforcement.  Do not try this without professional help.

Answer (score 2):

Hire someone to do that manually.

Or if you want to be scalable, use a crowdsourced solution like [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome).

Comment: That fails the "Using Python" criteria. Unless you can train snakes to do it.

Comment: Didn't she already suggest exactly that (using a person with expertise in this field) in the title of her question? :) Tsk, tsk on the non-PC choice of words, though.

Comment: You can access Mechanical Turk with Python.